# Boost Interprocess cannot find boost/config/user.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, boost-interprocess

I am compiling a Boost Interprocess example:

```
#include <interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;

   if(argc == 1){  //Parent process
      //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
      struct shm_remove
      {
         shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
         ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      } remover;

      //Create a shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write);

      //Set size
      shm.truncate(1000);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

      //Write all the memory to 1
      std::memset(region.get_address(), 1, region.get_size());

      //Launch child process
      std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
      if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
         return 1;
   }
   else{
      //Open already created shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (open_only, "MySharedMemory", read_only);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_only);

      //Check that memory was initialized to 1
      char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < region.get_size(); ++i)
         if(*mem++ != 1)
            return 1;   //Error checking memory
   }
   return 0;
}
```

but I was getting a compile error:

```
fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Now the file does exist and I was able to fix the error by including the missing header file:

g++    -c -g -I../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost -I../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0/libs **-include ../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/config.hpp** -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp

but after doing that I now get another error about a similar file:

```
./../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/config.hpp:30:29: fatal error: boost/config/user.hpp: No such file or directory
 #  include BOOST_USER_CONFIG
```

What is going on? Why won't this compile?

Comment: why don't you include the header with boost directory: `#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>` ?

Comment: @vasek I took the example from the Boost documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html so I didn't think I needed to?

Comment: when i change includes to `boost/interprocess` and compile with `-lrt` flag, it [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3946c9f5215b0af6).

Comment: but in those examples you can see there is `boost/` prefix in includes.

Comment: g++ -lrt   -c -g -I../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/interprocess -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:49: fatal error: interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your includes for boost library to the directory with `boost` subdirectory so that all the internal boost includes are found.

So if you change your build commandline to

```
g++ -lrt -c -g -I../../../space/dist/boost/boost_1_66_0 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp main.cpp
```

and change your includes to match boost documentation your code [will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3946c9f5215b0af6):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
```